# Finding the general term of $x_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the general term of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb ,N}$, $a>0$, defined by the recurrence relation

$$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\dfrac{a}{x_n^2}\right), $$

**EDIT** - consider the case $x_0>0$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please, tell us: 1) what is the context of the problem?  Is it homework?  2) What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  We'll be more than happy to help if you can elaborate some.

Comment: Why do you want this? It's probably not illuminating at all.

Comment: @Ihf is that at me, or the OP?

Comment: I assume that your task really is to prove that the sequence converges (towards the cube root of $a$). I further assume that you have covered the basic theorem about the convergence of bounded monotone sequences. Here's the first thing you should do. Try the sequence with $a=2$ and an initial value, say $x_1=1$, (that you also left out, so the sequence is still underdefined!). What do you observe? How does the sequence behave? Is it monotonous? Is there another pattern in its behavior that might be useful?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen my task is to find the general term. The other things are pieces of cake.

Comment: If you say so. Can't help you with that I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't understand the down- and close-votes. It is a legitimate question, certainly not off-topic, but probably very difficult to answer.

Comment: IT HAS A GENERAL TERM! DON'T DOWNVOTE/CLOSE IF YOU DON'T KNOW MATHEMATICS! IS THERE ANY OP HERE?

Comment: Agree with O.L. in that the question is legit. I also agree with lhf in the sense that I don't see the point of finding the general formula (without a background story). I could be willing to assist in proving convergence, but that is not of interest this time. I admit my inability to find a general formula.

Comment: A suggestion: explain why you need the general term.

Comment: After playing with it for quite a bit, I’m rather doubtful that there is a reasonable closed form for $x_n$. If there is, I suspect that one will need a very clever idea or a lot of luck to find it. (I frankly don’t understand why anyone cares why you want the general term.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if a closed form for $x_n$ exists. However, it can be shown that  $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt[3]{a_n}$ as follows:-

If ${x_n}$ converges, $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}=1$. Dividing recurrence relation by $x_n$ and taking limit to $\infty$ (Let $\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=x$):-
$$1=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{a}{x^3})\implies x^3=a \implies x = \sqrt[3]{a}$$